# Efficiently upgrading multiple environments to 2.2.5

Tags: upgrade, git

We are a multi-environment shop where each dev has their own environment, then we have a development, staging, and production.

I am trying to find the cleanest, most efficient way for each dev to be able to upgrade their own environments, and then of course upgrade dev, staging, and prod.

Is there a possibility of upgrading one environment via composer/command line, committing the changed files to a branch, and then merging that branch with the other environments?  If not, I'm open to suggestions here.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to get a way of doing it? Maybe i'll need it in the future. Thanks :D

Comment: @Raül unfortunately, no :(

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade using composer, using the command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After upgrading, check your Magento version with the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

You have to make sure all your extensions are compatible with the newer version of Magento. If not, you will need to disable the modules and upgrade them programatically until they are compatible with the newer version.

If your extensions have been installed via composer, upgrade them using the commands given by the extension creators.

All this changes can be done in a dev environment and then of course cloned to another environment. Hope it helps.